# Is there a keyboard shortcut in the Q&A box for double indenting blocks of code?

Tags: support

From time to time I need to include code under a bullet list or number list. When I do this I have to indent blocks of code 8 spaces instead of the typical 4. Is there a keyboard shortcut that will do this? I often use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to do this, but selecting a block and doing this just undoes the indenting in this scenario.

Here's an example of the code block I'm talking about in case you're unaware of this technique.

#### Normal block of code (4 spaces)

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "hello U&L world"
```

#### Block of code under a list (8 spaces)

1. some list item #1

   ```
   #!/bin/bash        
   echo "hello U&L world #1"
   ```
2. some list item #2

   ```
   #!/bin/bash    
   echo "hello U&L world #2"
   ```
3. some list item #3

   ```
   #!/bin/bash    
   echo "hello U&L world #3"
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a really cool usersript that does just that: it enables using <kbd>tab</kbd> for indenting code in the SE editor.

https://stackapps.com/q/3247/17253

Hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> twice will double indent so you can easily use it to format code in lists. I've been using this for a few days and can't understand how I lived without it!

Comment: Confirmed it works. Thanks! Nice dig!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, but there's a pretty quick workaround described in [WMD: Code inside lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126226/wmd-code-inside-lists) on the main meta:

- Indent the code 4 spaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- Add a single non-space character to the beginning of the first line
- Indent the code 4 more spaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (the non-space character tricks the editor into thinking it needs to indent)
- Remove the character you added to the first line

Comment: Thanks Michael, I couldn't find it when I searched.